# posting file in form data using JavaWS

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, java-ws

In postman I post form data to an API built on play2 framework. Now I want to make this same call in another API build on play2 framework.

```
ws.url(url).setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
       .post("key1=value1&key2=value2");
```

can be used to submit form data but how do I add a file to the same request?

Using play framework 2.4.X

Comment: Are you trying to submit form data AND file in the same request? Or you just want to submit a file?

Comment: "trying to submit form data AND file in the same request" - yes.
justlike in postman for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [play website](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaWS), you can find the following code to implement what you want.
Note that the document is for play version of 2.5.X

```
import play.mvc.Http.MultipartFormData.*;

//the file you want to post
Source<ByteString, ?> file = FileIO.fromFile(new File("hello.txt"));

//generate the right format for posting
FilePart<Source<ByteString, ?>> fp = new FilePart<>("hello", "hello.txt", "text/plain", file);

DataPart dp = new DataPart("key", "value");// the data you want to post

ws.url(url).post(Source.from(Arrays.asList(fp, dp)));
```

**update:**
The first thing you should know is that `ws` is built on `com.ning.http.AsyncHttpClient`. As referred to [Play Document](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaFileUpload), 
the `ws` of `play 2.4.*` does not support multi part form upload directly. You can use the underlying client `AsyncHttpClient` with [RequestBuilder.addBodyPart](https://asynchttpclient.github.io/async-http-client/apidocs/com/ning/http/client/RequestBuilder.html). The following code can fulfillment what you want

```
import com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient
import com.ning.http.client.multipart.FilePart

AsyncHttpClient myClient = ws.getUnderlying();
FilePart myFilePart = new FilePart("myFile", new java.io.File("test.txt"))
myClient.preparePut("http://localhost:9000/index").addBodyPart(filePart).execute.get()
```

have a good luck

Comment: the `ws` of play 2.4.x does not support  multi part form upload, but you can fulfill this function with the help of `AsyncHttpClient`. I have update the answer and I have tried it with scala, it works